# Flat clustering with metric conditions

Tags: machine-learning

With given metric for objects in my set, I need to form clusters with two conditions:

- Distance between any object in cluster his and farthest neighbor must less then t1.
- Distance between any object in cluster his and nearest neighbor must less then t2.

At the moment I'm using agglomerative clustering with an overridden metric funciton (0 for far objects), but it doesn't feel quite right.

[image]

Comment: *Clustering with Constraints* seems to be hard. How many samples you got and how big is the feature-dimension?

Comment: @sascha one feature, about 15 thousand samples.

Comment: And what's the metric?

Comment: @sascha variation of Levenshtein distance

Comment: And what is the origin of your side-constraints? Information to improve clusters? Or why these constraints? It looks, that there is a huge amount of instances which are infeasible then. And when given data, it might be even hard to select t1 and t2, as they are somehow entangled.

Comment: @sascha > information to improve clusters , yes. In fact, cluster is variations of one word collocation. > It might be even hard to select t1 and t2, Why? We are talking about one - demential clusters.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds, that you are converting a non-constrained problem to a constrained-one by adding side-information which should help the final clusters (sometimes these values could help, sometimes they could worsen the result). Maybe it might be better to stick to better-clustering algorithms. Your problem is kind of easy. Search for univariate clustering. It should be possible to solve it efficiently with a global-solution (no local ones).

Comment: @sascha I can't use univariate clustering, because features doesn't have coordinates, only metric between each sample.

Comment: visualizing might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach 1: SAT solving

For n objects, all possible clusterings can be described by a symmetric binary matrix {0, 1}^{n \times n}. The element at position (i, j) describes if object i is in the same clustering as object j. This means you would have

```
(n^2 + n)/2 - n = n^2 - n
```

binary variables. In your case it would be 224 985 000 variables. That is a lot. However, as you can reduce this to a SAT solving problem it might still be doable. I guess depends on how many clusterings fulfill the constraint but are still bad.

Now you can make this a boolean satisfiability problem:

> Distance between any object in cluster his and farthest neighbor must less then t1.

Some elements of the matrix are set to 0 by this constraint, as they are too far apart.

> Distance between any object in cluster his and nearest neighbor must less then t2.

I guess you mean the nearest neighbor in the cluster. This means either o is in no cluster (e.g. if o has the index i, then (i, j) = 0 for all j) or one of a pre-computable set of j has to be 1. So for each object with index i you get constraints here like

```
((i, 0) = 0 and (i, 1) = 0 and ... and (i,i)=1 and ... and (i,n)=0)
or
((i, k1)=1 or (i, k2)=1 or (i, k3)=1)
```

where dist(i, k_j) < t2.

Now you can either try to simply iterate through many solutions and find the best (e.g. [silhouette coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/224451/25741)) or you can try more elaborate methods. See [constrained optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization) for some more information.

### Approach 2: DBSCAN

You could use DBSCAN (or one of the algorithms of this family) with epsilon = t2. Then - if necessary - split clusters if they don't fulfill the first condition.